# AWK--Comparing the value of two variables in two different files

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have two text files A.txt and B.txt. Each line of A.txt A.txt

```
100
222
398
```

B.txt

```
1  2  103  2 
4  5  1026 74
7  8  209  55
10 11 122  78
```

What I am looking for is an awk command for doing this:

```
for each line of A 
    search B;
    if (the value of third column in a line of B - the value of the variable in A > 10)
        print that line of B;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should solve your problem:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
A="$HOME/a.txt"
B="$HOME/b.txt"

cat $A | while read a; do
    cat $B | while read b; do
        b3=$(echo $b | awk ' { print $3 }')
        c=$(($b3 - $a))
        if (( $c > 10 )); then
            echo $b
        fi
    done
done
```

Don't forget to make it executable using the following command:

```
chmod +x script_name
```

Comment: It seems that your code only compares the variables with the same line number. What I need is to search whole B.txt and if the condition is true print that line of B.

Comment: @user208434 Ah, that's more simple. Sorry, I didn't understood well your request.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
while read i; do awk -v i="$i" '$3-i>10' file2; done < file1
```

**Explanation:**

- `while read i; do ... ; done < file1` : This iterates through file one, saving the value it finds there (the entire line) as `$i`.
- `awk -v i=$i '$3-i>10' file2` : This goes through file2 and prints each line where the third field is less than the current value of `$i`. The trick is passing the variable to the `awk` script with the `-v var_name=value` option.

Note that this (and Radu's) answer, will print *each* line that matches for *each* variable. The result will be many duplicated lines, to remove them use `sort`:

```
while read i; do awk -v i="$i" '$3-i>10' file2; done < file1 | sort -u
```